# Is this how you incorporate an Onload Event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onload

I have a quick question. I am trying to incorporate an onload event in HTML5. Here is my code but it refuses to work. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Animation</title>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('videoBackground').onload = function()
        {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animCD.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>

    <video id="videoBackground" poster="img/loading.png" onload="function()" width="1920" height="1080" preload="auto" onprogress="animCD_onprogress();" onended="animCD_start();">
        <source id="colorVid_mp4" type="video/mp4" src="img/luther_color.mp4">      
    </video>
```

Comment: the head and html tags are closed in your original html?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it refuses to work"? Do you see any errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `someElement.onload = function() { }` *is* how you create an onload handler in a general sense. The reason your doesn't work is that your script block comes before the element in question and runs immediately, at which point `document.getElementById()` can't find that element because it hasn't been parsed yet.

**You can fix this by moving the script block to somewhere after the element (many people put their scripts at the end of the body),** or by calling it in an onload handler for the page:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('videoBackground').onload = function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
};
```

Although the page/window's onload should be called after all content is loaded, so I'm not sure that there's any point creating more onload handlers from there.

I notice you also have an `onload="function()"` attribute in your html. That is another way to specify a handler, although inline event attributes are not the preferred way to do things, but you'd need to put an actual function name `onload="someFunction()"` to call a named function defined elsewhere, or put the code directly:

```
<video ... onload="document.body.style.backgroundColor='black';" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the point where you are executing `getElementById('videoBackground')` the element with the id `videoBackground` doesn't exist yet.

Either move the script below where you created the `videoBackground` element or run the script after the DOM loads using `document.onload`.

Comment: I said the same thing in my answer, but I wonder: would putting that code in the document's onload handler work given that the document onload should happen after all its content has finished loading and thus that would be _after_ the video has loaded, too late to apply an onload handler to the video?

Comment: @nnnnnn: You're partially right. It's too late (for what the OP really wants to do) to fire the code on the **window.onload** event. But it's not too late for the **document.onload** event.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the fact that window.onload would have been too late.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification. Is that timing true of all browsers? (It's been so long since I've used an onload handler that I don't remember - I usually use jQuery's document ready and/or put my scripts at the end.)

Comment: Not sure. There's that whole DOMContentLoaded thing on IE. So I don't think document.onload has reliable cross-browser behavior.