# How to switch image when onload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to show the image (from css id) inside div (in html). The image has to match with the template. Every user has a different template, so they need different image shown on the body view.

So far, this is my attempt:

HTML

```
<div id="logoHeader"></div>
```

CSS

```
    #logoheader_1 {
    height: 100px;
    background: url("/logoheader_1.png") left 20px no-repeat;
     }
   #logoheader_2 {
   height: 100px;
   background: url("/logoheader_2.jpg") left 20px no-repeat;
    }
```

JS

```
var templates = 1; // This is just example of if user A using template 1

switch(templates) {
  case '1'
    document.getElementById("logoHeader").onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("logoheader_1");
    };
  break;
  case '2'
    document.getElementById("logoHeader").onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("logoheader_2");
    };
  break;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arifams/aunxpL3c/)

Well, it doesn't work up until now. Would you please help me how to show the proper image at the div body for each template?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you even took  a look at the console ?

Comment: Yes, it said `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` reffered to `document.getElementById("logoHeader").onload = function()`. I do believe my syntax is not right. Followed this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486094/is-this-how-you-incorporate-an-onload-event still didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first of all, your [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/switch) syntax is wrong, and you were trying to compare string with number value (ie. `1` with `'1'`) which doesn't work with switch statement as it uses [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()).

Then I suggest you tu use classes instead of identifiers to change the style of an element.

Finally, the `load` event is not available on `div` elements, so I called it on the window in order to be sure that the div is loaded and ready to be used.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var templates = 1;

  switch (templates) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById('logoHeader').classList.add('logoheader_1');
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById('logoHeader').classList.add('logoheader_2');
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.logoheader_1 {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.logoheader_2 {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoHeader"></div>
```